# Application Pool Crashes when Web Site is Not Running as Network Service

Tags: c#, .net, iis, crystal-reports, application-pool

I have a site running Crystal Reports Viewer in IIS 7 but for security reasons we want it to run the application pool under the ApplicationPoolIdentity. We noticed the application pool keeps crashing when we switched it from Network Service to ApplicationPoolIdentity and we want to give extra permissions to the ApplicationPoolIdentity on certain folders on the drive in order to remedy this situation.

The problem is, we gave a ton of permissions to different folders, but as far as we can tell we cannot pinpoint why the application pool keeps crashing and what file it cannot access.

We checked a lot of different log files, but maybe we skipped over some that could be of more importance. Is there anything out there to show us where the problem is, whether it be a certain log I haven't come across or some sort of tracing I can use to get to the files that I need to give this identity permissions?

The pool crashes when trying to load Crystal Reports Viewer and gives no errors, just says it is unreachable.

Comment: IIRC Crystal Reports Viewer is a COM object... they usually require special case regarding permissions and might even be unreliable because some COM objects need a "desktop" to work correctly... not really sure whether Crystal Reports Viewer is one of those BUT I would recommend asking the vendor what configuration/permission are needed in your scenario...

Comment: Have you tried looking in the eventviewer? start->run->eventvwr.msc

Comment: @Yahia I think you are correct. If you answer this question then I can mark your answer as acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC Crystal Reports Viewer is a COM object... they usually require special case regarding permissions and might even be unreliable because some COM objects need a "desktop" to work correctly... not really sure whether Crystal Reports Viewer is one of those BUT I would recommend asking the vendor what configuration/permission are needed in your scenario...

Answer (score 1):

Actually you may be able to get this to work by setting the permissions correctly for appPoolIdentity. See the following post on the IIS team blog.

http://blogs.iis.net/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/10/02/tip-98-did-you-know-the-default-application-pool-identity-in-iis-7-5-windows-7-changed-from-networkservice-to-apppoolidentity.aspx